# How to use TFS sendmail API with TFS2018?

Tags: email, tfs

TFS created the [sendmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/send-mail/send-mail?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) API with the version 7.0 of their API. Is it possible to call this API from a TFS2018 server ?

According to the [supported versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops) chart, it is not possible to call a 7.0 API with TFS2018, but is there a workaround ?

Otherwise, how can I send an email when a work item is modified (I didn't find this functionality in service hooks events) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If email is configured, the standard email alert features of Azure DevOps can send an email when work items are changed. The TFS Server must have email configured in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console.

[image]

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops

Comment: Yes, thank you. In my case it doesn't work because this solution isn't customizable at all, I can't choose what the mail looks like, what information to pass on etc... But it can be good for people who want a quick solution to set up.

Comment: Yeah, if you want a customized email, then you're on your own.

Answer (score 1):

After more research, I concluded that there's no way to send a mail from the TFS API with the TFS2018 version. So I called my own API from a service hook, and with this API I send a mail using SMTP.